# A question in entrance exam to high school for gifted students

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The problem below is from the entrance exam to a high school for gifted students in Vietnam that I struggled to solve.

**Problem:**

Given a 10x10 board populated by the set of 100 integers 1, 2, 3, ..., 100. Prove that there exists two adjacent cells with the difference is at least 10.

A pair of two adjacent cells is defined as two cells in the same column or the same row.

**A translated online solution:**

Suppose the difference between two numbers in arbitrary adjacent cells less than or equal to 9.

Let $S$ be the set of all numbers that are largest in every column and row and $m$ is the smallest number in $S$.

Without loss of generality, let $m$ be the largest number in row $i$.

Given an arbitrary column $j$, let $M$ be the largest number in that column and $a$ is the number on row $i$ column $j$. We have the inequality

$$
M \geq m \geq a
$$

Since the difference between two adjacent numbers is less than or equal to 9, there must be a number in column $j$ belongs to the set $A = \{m, m+1, ..., m+8\}$

Hence, here is at least one number in $A$ in every column. There are in total 10 columns, so a number must be filled in two columns (contradiction)

**The part I don't understand**

there must be a number in column $j$ belongs to the set $A = \{m, m+1, ..., m+8\}$

**Reference:**

https://youtu.be/_fFekS4AgrE

Comment: OK, so tell us the different ways you tried.

Comment: @TedShifrin there is an online solution in Vietnamese and their logic makes no sense to me. `struggle to understand` -> `struggle to solve`

Comment: Can you provide the solution and point out what you can't understand?

Comment: @IraeVid updated

Comment: If $m$ is in column $j$, we are done. If not, we must have $M>m>a$.  As we move vertically from $a$ to $M$ we can at most move by $9$.  Hence there is no way to "skip over" the numbers in $\{m+1, m+2, \cdots, m+8\}$.

Comment: @lulu got it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $m$ is in column $j$ we are done, so suppose it isn't.  In that case we have strict inequalities $$M>m>a$$

Now look at the steps between $a$ and $M$. Let's denote them as $a=a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_k=M$.  There must be a stage at which $a_r<m$ but $a_{r+1}>m$.  Since $a_r<m$ we must have $a_r≤m-1$ so $m<a_{r+1}≤m+8$ and we are done.